# How to set httpOnly flag for Abp.AuthToken cookie?

Tags: boilerplate, abp

We are planning to build site using abpboilerplate  (Augular) framework .in that we noticed that abp.authtoken cookie is setting without httponly flag and also cookie is setting using Angular code. Setting cookie without httponly is not good practise .Can anyone advise whether can set httponly for abp.authtoken ? or it is really abp boilerplate framework limitation

Answer (score 0):

You can configure application cookies at startup like:

```cs
services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
{
    options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
});
```